# Julia - getting parameters at runtime inside of an at runtime created function

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

Im trying to create a macro that replaces the body of a function such that:

```
@foo function bar(a,b,c)
   *my code here*
end
```

and I've gotten quite far, but *my code here* needs to know the parameters of `bar(...)` which can be done
by using `Base.@locals`. But the issue is that `@foo` would need to insert it and I think it's using the wrong 'local scope' or is evaluated before there are parameters.

foo looks roughly like this: (`expr.args[2]` is the function body)

```
macro foo(expr::Expr)
    ...
    expr.args[2] = quote
        locals = Base.@locals
        println(locals)
        ...
    end
    
    :($expr)
end
```

But calling the later created function by this, only prints out an empty dict, whereas a manually created function does print out the parameters when using the same code:

```
function test(a,b,c)
    println(Base.@locals)
end
test(1,2,3) # returns: Dict{Symbol,Any}(:a => 1,:b => 2,:c => 3)
```

So my question is, how do I have to work around this so that `Base.@locals` (or a similar method) gives me the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than relying on `Base.@locals`, I'd get the function arguments directly from the definition, and do something like this:

```
using MacroTools

macro foo(expr)
    def = MacroTools.splitdef(expr)

    make_pair(arg) = :($(Meta.quot(arg)) => $arg)
    def[:body] = quote
        d = Dict($(map(make_pair, def[:args])...))
        println(d)
        $(def[:body])
    end

    MacroTools.combinedef(def)
end
```

A few remarks and explanations about this code:

- Macros trying to rewrite/modify function definitions can greatly benefit from using the `splitdef` and `combinedef` functions from [`MacroTools`](https://fluxml.ai/MacroTools.jl/stable/utilities/). Globally, the proposed macro features 3 stages:

  1. split the function definition into separate parts;
  2. insert the code you want at the beginning of the function body;
  3. re-combine all parts (including the modified body) into a legit function definition.
- The dictionary containing function arguments is built from the following key ingredients:

  - `make_pair` takes a given variable name (as a symbol, say `:a`), and returns an expression evaluating to the pair `:a => a`;
  - this `make_pair` function is then `map`ped to all arguments coming from the (decomposed) function definition, in order to build an array of argument pairs;
  - finally this array is splatted into the `Dict` constructor.

We can check that this example function definition expands to the expected code:

```
julia> Base.remove_linenums!(@macroexpand @foo function bar(a,b,c)
           a + b + c
       end)
:(function Main.bar(var"#26#a", var"#27#b", var"#28#c"; )
      var"#25#d" = Main.Dict(:a => var"#26#a", :b => var"#27#b", :c => var"#28#c")
      Main.println(var"#25#d")
      begin
          var"#26#a" + var"#27#b" + var"#28#c"
      end
  end)
```

... and more generally that everything works as expected at runtime too:

```
julia> @foo function bar(a, b, c)
           a + b + b
       end
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar(1, 2, 3)
Dict(:a => 1,:b => 2,:c => 3)
5
```